# Sending Query String and Session information using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, session, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax to create comments and its not working , and i am not sure where the problem is. I am thinking it might be in the way i am reading UserID and VideoID

I have UserID saved in a session, and the videoID is saved in Query String.
am i reading them wrong?! if yes how can i read them?

here is my js code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnPost').click(function (e) {

            $.ajax({

                url: "Ajax/ProcessAddComment.aspx",
                data: {
                    commenttext: $('.txtcomment').val(),
                    videoid: Request.QueryString["d"],

            userid: $.session.get('UserID')
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);

                },
                error: function () {

                }

            });



        });


        $.ajax({
            url: "Ajax/ProcessFindComment.aspx",
            data: { videoid: Request.QueryString["id"] },
            success: function (data) {
                 // Append to the bottom
                // of list while prepend
                // to the top of list

                $('.postlist').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });




    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [this plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) to get and set your session.

I think your problem is: `Request.QueryString`

Try using the following JS function to get a value from the querystring rather than that:

```
function (key) {
    if (!key) return '';
    key = key.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&"); // escape RegEx meta chars
    var match = location.search.match(new RegExp("[?&]" + key + "=([^&]+)(&|$)"));
    return (match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "))) || '';
};
```

**Note:** you can use the network tab in your developer window (F12 in most browsers) to see the Ajax data. The error console in there should tell you if there's a JavaScript error, and the network tab should tell you what was in the Ajax request and response.

Comment: im not using any plugin actually, Im working on Visual Studios Asp.net